# Getting reference to control dropped on after dragdrop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to drag and drop so that when the drop takes place, I can access data about the control that was dragged and the control that is dropped on. But the alert in this function:

```
function onDragEnd(e)
{
    if (!e)
    e = event;
var callee =  e.target || e.srcElement;
    alert(callee.innerHTML);
if (event.srcElement.tagName=='A')
    { var srcCell = callee.parentElement; }
else
    { var srcCell = callee; }

}
```

shows information about the what is being dragged, not the control dropped on. How can I get a reference to the whatever is being 'dropped on'?

Fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/4Dg63/3/

Don't want to use jquery for this.

Answer (score 0):

You must use ondrop event to get info about target. Ondragend is event, that says "Hey, that element got dropped. I have no idea where.". while ondrop says "Hey, something just landed on me. What should I do with it?".

What you were doing seemed interesting to me, so I rewrote is (also, I couldn't look at your coding style, sorry for that :D).

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TaaQH/2/

And code here:

HTML:

```
<table id="container">
    <tr><td>Rich</td><td>2050</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Some Guy</td><td>100</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Poor</td><td>2</td></tr>
</table>

<div draggable="true">The drag won't work with me, because I'm div and not a tr...</div>

<table>
    <tr draggable="true">
        <td style="border: 1px solid black">I'm table cell, but still, it won't work with me, because I'm not in the same table as target</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#container td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function addEvent(object, eventType, callback) {
    if (object.addEventListener) {
        object.addEventListener(eventType, callback, false);
    } else {
        object.attachEvent('on' + eventType, callback);
    }
}


function isInTable(table, row) {
    return [].indexOf.call(table.rows, row) > -1;
}

function getData(row) {
    var cells = row.cells;
    return {
        'name': cells[0].innerHTML,
        'money': parseInt(cells[1].innerHTML)
    };
}

function getMoneyAmount(row) {
    return getData(row).money;
}

function setMoneyAmount(row, newAmount) {
    row.cells[1].innerHTML = newAmount;
}

function changeTokenAmount(row, amount) {
    setMoneyAmount(row, getMoneyAmount(row) + amount);
}

function transferTokens(rowFrom, rowTo, amount) {
    if (getMoneyAmount(rowFrom) >= amount) {
        changeTokenAmount(rowFrom, -amount);
        changeTokenAmount(rowTo, amount);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function prepareTable(table) {
    var rows = table.rows,
        rowCount = rows.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        rows[i].draggable = 'true';
    }
}

function handleRowDrop(e) {
    if (!sourceRow || !isInTable(container, sourceRow)) {
        return false;
    }

    e.preventDefault();

    var targetRow = e.target.parentNode,
        dataFrom = getData(sourceRow),
        dataTo = getData(targetRow);

    if (sourceRow === targetRow) {
        return false;
    }

    if (transferTokens(sourceRow, targetRow, 1)) {
        alert('1 token transferred from ' + dataFrom.name + ' to ' + dataTo.name)
    } else {
        alert(dataFrom.name + ' doesn\'t have enough tokens!');
    }

    sourceRow = false;
}


var container = document.getElementById('container'),
    sourceRow = false;

prepareTable(container);


addEvent(container, 'drop', handleRowDrop);
addEvent(container, 'dragstart', function (e) {
    sourceRow = e.target;
});
addEvent(container, 'dragover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My 'coding style' is what jsfiddle seems to do by default. I get bored trying to improve the layout. I probably should have made clear I need something that will work on all versions of IE (at least back to 7.0).